# howto use passprompt_override in sudoers file?

Tags: debian-jessie, sudoers

I had, on a prior machine, used passprompt_override in the sudoers file to change the prompt to:

`ENTER NUCLEAR LAUNCH CODE:` (instead of the old boring `enter password:`)
But now, for the life of me, I can't recall how to do it, like what to actually add to/write in the file, and the man page isn't particularly forthcoming with examples, does anyone know how to use this feature?

If it's relevant, I'm on Debian/Jessie 8.5

Comment: Try searching for "prompt" in man 5 sudoers.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend adding and alias to your .bashrc file instead of modifying your sudoers file. you can accomlish this by doing the following:

1.open your .bashrc file

2.go to the section that has `ls` alias's

3.at the bottom of the list type the following:

```
 alias sudo='sudo --prompt="ENTER NUCLEAR LAUNCH CODE:"'
```

4.save and close the file

5.Test

Make sure you add the last single quote or else it wont work.

Comment: That is super interesting. I'd have never thought of this.

Answer (score 0):

Use visudo to modify your sudoers policy; add the following line.

> Defaults passprompt="ENTER NUCLEAR LAUNCH CODE:"

You may have to *also* add the following line.

> Defaults passprompt_override

https://www.sudo.ws/man/1.8.16/sudoers.man.html